# Does jerky need to be preserved with nitrites?

Tags: food-safety, jerky

I found some chicken jerky in the store that does not contain nitrites/nitrates or celery extract. Is it safe that way? Is it because it is dried? Thank you!

These are the ingredients from their website:

INGREDIENTS: CHICKEN BREAST, BROWN SUGAR, SUGAR, CHICKEN BROTH, FLAVORINGS, LESS THAN 2% SALT, SUN-DRIED TOMATO, GLYCERIN, FRUCTOSE, YEAST EXTRACT, BROMELAIN (FROM PINEAPPLES), ORANGE JUICE POWDER(CORN SYRUP, ORANGE JUICE SOLIDS), WATER, CITRIC ACID.

And the pork one:

INGREDIENTS: PORK, SUGAR, WATER, LESS THAN 2% SALT, SOY SAUCE [(WHEAT, SOYBEANS, SALT), MALTODEXTRIN], FLAVORING, SESAME SEEDS, YEAST EXTRACT, SESAME OIL

Comment: Can you include a photo of the nutrition label (with the ingredients list)? That will help us explain what's likely giving it shelf stability.

Comment: Please use the edit button on the question to add this information to the body of the question rather than as a comment.

Comment: "Flavorings" is likely to include celery, which is a source of nitrates. Celery is a common home kitchen nitrate ingredient which is why it's in so many recipes where celery isn't really a star ingredient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your nitrite-free jerky is safe to eat. Nitrites are only one possible method of preservation, along with smoking and salting the food.

Comment: Welcome Victoria - I removed the health claim from your answer because it is specifically off topic for this site.